# Pascal: sentence after an if

Tags: pascal

Im just starting up with pascal and I'm doing the good old bhaskara solver with the following code:

```
    Program bhaskara;
var
    a,b,c: real;
begin
    writeln('Ingrese a, b y c');
    readln(a,b,c);
    if sqr(b) >= 4*a*c then
        begin
        writeln('tiene raices reales');
        end
    else
        begin
        writeln('no tiene raices reales');
        end
    readln(a);
end.
```

The last line: readln(a), which is there just to pause the program and see the output is making the program not compile(program works fine without it), it says:

```
bhaskara.pas(15,2) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier READLN" found
```

Im sure it's something simple but i can't find the answer, please help.

Comment: I think you quoted the error incorrectly. It's complaining about no `;` before your `readln(a);` (in other words, you need `;` after the `end` before the `readln`).

Comment: that was from a prevoius attempt to compile, i edited it now

Comment: Ok now it works after adding the ";" Thanks!

Comment: But do you understand why it works now but didn't before?

Comment: I guess the whole if block counts as another line, so I have to separate it with (;)? I was studying this from some examples and they didn't include any code after the if

Comment: The error exactly tells you what is wrong: the compiler expects a `;` but it finds a `READLN`. So put a `;` after the `end`of the `else` block. And the whole **if** clause is `if <condition> then <statement1> else <statement2>` (the **else** part can be omitted). Because more code follows, you must separate that with a semicolon from the next line of code. The parts ´<statement1>` and `<statement2>` can be a single statement, or they can be a **compound** statement, i.e. a `begin`-`end` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal requires a semicolon as a statement separator **between** statements.

Your `else` block is a statement and because it is not the final line
of the program and is followed by your `readln(a)`, it requires a ';' 
after it.

In fact, because your `else` clause contains only a single statement,
it does not require the `begin` & `end`.

So you could simply write

```
else
  writeln('no tiene raices reales');
readln(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon (;) after the "end" statement right before the readln statement.